# Laravel ACL Errors in Console Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::where()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, acl

I'm currently new to Laravel and trying to learn it. I worked now many hours with it and tried to install and use now the Laravel ACL from https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl
But I keep getting errors with it.

My Steps:

1. Installed
2. tried `php artisan migrate` -> not worked -> `Nothing to migrate.`
3. tried it manually -> copying the migration files from `vendor>mateusjunges>laravel-acl>database>migrations>` into `..database>migrations`
4. Again `php artisan migrate` -> worked
5. tried `php artisan permission:create testperm testperm "test"`-> error

Error:

```
    Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::where()

  at testproject\vendor\mateusjunges\laravel-acl\src\Console\Commands\CreatePermission.php:43
     39▕     public function handle()
     40▕     {
     41▕         $permissionModel = app(config('acl.models.permission'));
     42▕
  ➜  43▕         $permission = $permissionModel->where('slug', $this->argument('slug'))
     44▕             ->orWhere('name', $this->argument('name'))
     45▕             ->first();
     46▕
     47▕         if (! is_null($permission)) {

  1   testproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Junges\ACL\Console\Commands\CreatePermission::handle()

  2   testproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
```

6. tried `php artisan user:permissions 1` -> next error

Error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::find()

  at testproject\vendor\mateusjunges\laravel-acl\src\Console\Commands\UserPermissions.php:44
     40▕         $userParameter = $this->argument('user');
     41▕         $userModel = app(config('acl.models.user'));
     42▕
     43▕         if (is_numeric($userParameter)) {
  ➜  44▕             $user = $userModel->find((int) $userParameter);
     45▕         } elseif (is_string($userParameter)) {
     46▕             $table = config('acl.tables.users');
     47▕             $columns = $this->verifyColumns($table);
     48▕

  1   testproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Junges\ACL\Console\Commands\UserPermissions::handle()

  2   testproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
```

I dont know what I did wrong, the installation was successful...

Answer (score 2):

You have to see the documentation of the package, it is going always to be hard if you try by your own...

This is the [documentation](https://mateusjunges.github.io/laravel-acl/guide/getting-started.html#installation), and it clearly says: To install run `php artisan acl:install`, and then you have one more that will add all the needed files you are missing (that's why the error) `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Junges\ACL\Providers\ACLServiceProvider" --tag="acl-migrations"`...

Read the documentation please...

Comment: sry should specify the install part, installed it with php artisan acl:install and for the part with vendor:publish i get the message:

Can't locate path: D:\test\testproject\vendor\mateusjunges\laravel-acl\src\Providers/database/migrations>

followed the documentation and followed some videos on yt..

Comment: I am not sure if it is a problem you are running that in windows. I think it should work... If you manually go to `D:\test\testproject\vendor\mateusjunges\laravel-acl\src\`, do you see `Provider` and more folder ? Also, if `Providers` is there, do you see `Providers/database/migrations` ?

Comment: thats the next problem... in `...Providers` there are no folders, only 3 files: `ACLAuthServiceProvider.php` `ACLEventsServiceProvider.php` `ACLServiceProvider.php`

Comment: Okay, having only those 3 files is okay, as if you see the [source code](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl/tree/master/src/Providers), you can see exactly those files. See this [source code](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl/blob/b7df37fcfc80f5709bb7ea228447f8978de51349/src/Providers/ACLServiceProvider.php#L93-L106), this one is executing and giving you error, what is the value of `config('acl.custom_migrations')` ? Try running that in `tinker` and share the value here.

Comment: you mean running `config('acl.custom_migrations')` in `php artisan tinker` ?

If so, i get `=> null`

Comment: Or you mean the value in the config? Its false